# How do I set up simple commerce to perform actions on a successful purchase/unsubscription?

Tags: members, ecommerce, paypal, commerce

I'm trying to set simple commerce to update a member field when a purchase has been made. How do I do this? I'd also like to do this when a user unsubscribes from our site.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write some custom code in the Simple Commerce module. Get the txn_type for the ipn then add a method to handle it. For an out of the box solution, check if memberr can do what you want.